# Passing Date objects between two differnet time zones without applying Time Zone conversions in java

Tags: java, datetime, date, timezone

I have two programs that are in two servers. Program A is in UK server and Program B in USA server.

I need to pass a date object from Program A to Program B. But when I get the date object from program B, I receive it with the Time Zone Conversion. How can I pass a date object from one server to another without applying this Time Zone conversions.

Note : I know that this thing can be done through Calender objects as follows. But **in my case I want to use Date objects.**

In Program B :

```
Date checkInDate  = new Date(cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900 , cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) , cal1.get(Calendar.DATE), cal1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal1.get(Calendar.MINUTE), cal1.get(Calendar.SECOND));
Date checkOutDate = new Date(cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900 , cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) , cal2.get(Calendar.DATE), cal2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal2.get(Calendar.MINUTE), cal2.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Comment: java.util.Calendar is used for representing dates and for date conversion also most of the methods in java.util.Date are deprecated... Why you dont want to use Calendar?

Comment: A java.util.Date is an absolute point in time, it has no timezone.  An example of the code that doesn't work as you expect would be immensely helpful in understanding your question :) also information on the method you're using to pass objects between servers.

Comment: How do you pass your dates? Web services? Through a DB and JDBC? Something else? The answer could be different from each transport, although usually converting to a 'known' timezone before transfer (GMT) is a good solution. Additionally, why would you not want a TZ conversion?

Comment: I am passing objects through java serializations

Comment: Serializing and deserializing `java.util.Date` does not apply any timezone effects. The `Date` deserialized will be the same as the `Date` serialized. If you are observing differences, it's because you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @sachinrahulsourav: You might be right. I infer from Namal's answer that he wants to be able to send a date like "19th of March 2012" to another system and preserve that value. A `Date` doesn't do that, because a `Date` is an instant in time. `Calendar` is closer, but because it includes a timezone, it's still not quite right.

Comment: Yes Tom and sachinrahulsourav. I totally agree with you. But I am working on a system that have been already developped. So, in first hand I tried to see whether arte there any way to do this. Anyway I knew that I'll get a lot of downvotes for this. but your ideas are worthier than them. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am implementing Serializable, I found that I can use following method too.

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
    oos.defaultWriteObject();
    if (null != checkInDate)
        oos.writeUTF(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm").format(checkInDate));
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException { 

    ois.defaultReadObject();
    try {
        setCheckInDate(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm").parse(ois.readUTF()));
    } catch (ParseException e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be much better off serialising your date using [Date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) which gives the number of milliseconds since the epoch (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT).  This is a completely unambiguous reference to a point in time.  You can re-create the date by calling the [Date(long date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) constructor.

Comment: This is not necessary. When Date is serialized, [it writes out exactly that value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.util.Date). Namal has a problem because he's doing something wrong, not because of troublesome behaviour of `Date`.

Comment: @TomAnderson, you're completely correct, I should have checked that first.

Comment: No problem. Keynes once wrote that "There is no harm in being sometimes wrong — especially if one is promptly found out"!